# How can I reconfigure these keys in .inputrc on Linux to do nothing?

Tags: linux, terminal

How can I reconfigure these keys in .inputrc on Linux (emulator) to do nothing?

On my machine pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + any arrow key outputs letters such as A and D. I am using [Termux](https://termux.com) (Linux emulator for Android).

This is terrible behaviour and must be stopped.

But how do I configure `.inputrc` to do absolutely nothing when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + any arrow key?

i.e.: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>. Four lines of code should suffice.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't correctly set `TERM`

Comment: So if that applies, how would I do so?